# How to make a python script continue running while mac is locked

Tags: python, macos

I'm currently working on a python script that takes some hours to finish. I'm working in a shared office and I want (if possible) lo lock my mac m1 in order to make sure nobody can access it and at the same time keep the script running.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but I can't imagine a Mac stopping processes that were running if you lock the desktop, unless if you mean you put the computer to sleep, at which point nothing is running (that would be the point of putting it to sleep). Can you be clear what behaviour you're seeing and how you would like to see that change?

Comment: It's easier to use a third party tool, like Amphetamine, for this instead of needing to do anything specific to your Python program at all. It's not like you _couldn't_ write code for the purpose, but if there's an easier way to solve your problem, why bother?

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12

Comment: i'm sorry to waste your time. i believed that locking the screen put in pause the execution (i've read this in some forum). I've checked myself with an easy script and the action of lock the pc with the physical button doesn't stop anything

Answer (score 5):

It can be done manually like so, assuming the system is plugged in throughout:

MacOS 13

1. Settings > Displays > Advanced... (bottom-right) > Prevent automatic sleeping on power adapter when the display is off - Turn on
2. Settings > Privacy & Security > Advanced... (bottom-right) > Log out automatically after inactivity - Turn off

MacOS 12

1. Settings > Battery > Power Adapter > Prevent your Mac from automatically sleeping when display is off
2. Settings > Security & Privacy > Advanced... (bottom-right) > make sure "Log out after [x] minutes" is disabled

Once you lock your screen now (Apple icon top-left or the power button), your computer should stay awake. Note that if you close the lid, the system will sleep